# IF and MATCH formula assistance

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2010 to sort data on desktop users at my workplace, specifically compare the most frequent user of a desktop with audit data on the last user of the desktop.

I need some help with creating an appropriate formula. Below is an example of  part of the spreadsheet I’m working with and details of what I want to achieve (apologies for the layout below, don't know how to make it more user-friendly).

```
  A     B          C                         D
1 PC #  Last User  Most Frequent User (MFU)  Does the MFU Match Last User?
2       mgrey      mgrey                     =IF(C2=B2,"Match","No Match")
3       lbrown     lbrown                    Match
4       dmustard   jburgund                  No Match
5       pturquoi   cwhite                    No Match
6       kaemeral   eyellow                   No Match
7       hred       hred                      Match
8       vescarle   pturquoi                  No Match
9       jburgund   fblue                     No Match
```

What I am trying to do is-
1.  Check if C2 = B2. (i.e. check if the Most Frequent User of the PC is also the Last User). I’m currently doing this via a formula in D: =IF(C2=B2,"Match","No Match")
2.  Then, I want to chck if a Most Frequent User of a PC is listed anywhere as a Last User (in column B). So if D2 is a “No Match” (i.e. if C2≠B2), look in all of Column B to see if it occurs elsewhere and return the cell reference. I don’t need to return multiple cell references for the same name.
I’m stuck at this point – the best my skills can do is: =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,B2:B10,1,FALSE)),"NOT FOUND","FOUND"), which only tells me if C2 occurs anywhere in Column B (including those items already identified as a Match). 
Would someone be able to give me a correct formula to complete this search?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Match() function returns the relative row number of the found item. If the range that Match looks in starts in row 1, the returned number will be the absolute row number of the found item. You can even combine it with the text "B" to create the illusion of a cell reference, since you are only looking in column B.

Try in cell E2 and copied down

```
=IF(D2="No Match",IFERROR("Found in B"&MATCH(C2,$B$1:$B$9,0),""),"")
```

[image]